# Laravel api resource only if its owned by user

Tags: laravel, laravel-resource

Lets say a `user` belongs to a `company` and each `company` has many `projects`. Now I wanna make an API resource for `projects`. For this, I wanna work with https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources

For example for the `show` method of the controller, I could do it with laravel route model binding like so:

```php
class ProjectController extends Controller {
    public function show(Project $project) {
        return new ProjectResource($project);
    }
}
```

This works as expected. But of course, the `user` (identified by a token - this is already working) should only see/list/update/delete `projects` from his `company` he belongs to.

Now I could forget about route model binding and do it manually like so:

```php
    public function show($id, Request $request) {
        $project = Project::query()
            ->where("id", $id)
            ->whereHas("company",function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('id', $request->user()->company_id);
            })
            ->first();

        return $project ? new ProjectResource($project) : Route::respondWithRoute('api.fallback.404');
    }
```

But is this they way to go? It looks like a dublication of code to implement this for all other resources (`offices`, `customers`, etc. which all belongs to a company) in the same way?

I could of course make it a bit nicer, with local scopes, but not sure if there aren't better ways?

Comment: Why not using Policies and `can` middleware?

Comment: Ah. Good point. But how to filter it on viewany? There I can only restrict based on class, right? And not on ownership? Btw you can write it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Policies** and **can** middleware.
For viewany scenario i suggest to consider global scopes. If your application should filter `Project` most of the times, then global scope should solve the problem.